# How to use terminal for working with xCode Command Line Tools?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, terminal, genstrings

*Context:* I have installed the Command Line Tools separately as the conventional method of
"xCode->Preferences->Downloads->Components->Command Line Tools->Install" didn't work for me.

*Purpose:* I need to implement internationalization/localization on my application and want to use *genstrings* for creating the Localizable.Strings files.

***Problem**:* When I try to use the Terminal and type command like

> $ find . -name *.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj

I Get:

> couldn't connect to output directory en.lproj

How should I specify the path for directory? Also, I might need to specify the path for some *.m files as well.

**Note**: I was suggested to read the [genstrings manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/genstrings.1.html) but I am not sure how to work with a particular xCode project while using the Terminal.

Comment: Well then wait until you are at the stage/window where you can enter the commands stated in the manual.

Comment: You don't need know all the command line tools to run genstrings. All you need to do is navigate to your project's home directory and run the genstrings commands that are needed.

Comment: @trojanfoe : The wait got over :)

Comment: @ashokbabuy: Thanks. Can you also help with connection to the output directory as stated in my edited question?

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to be taken care of:

1) After entering the Terminal, first go to the folder in which the targeted .m files are present. Use:

> cd "path"

2) While using the genstrings code, specify the complete path of the output directory. e.g.:

> genstrings -o /Users/kushalashok/Desktop/ProjectnName/en.lproj *.m

After running the code, a new file named "Localizable.strings" will be created in the specified output folder.